# How to compare different data types in LaTeX3

Tags: macros, expl3, latex3

I am trying to do basic comparison of values but am uncertain how to do it correctly (using LaTeX3 functionality only, so without `xifthen`).

From the documentation, these are the only generic if functions:

```
\if:w
\if_bool:N
\if_box_empty:N
\if_case:w
\if_catcode:w
\if_charcode:w
\if_cs_exist:N
\if_cs_exist:w
\if_dim:w 
\if_eof:w 
\if_false:
\if_hbox:N
\if_int_compare:w 
\if_int_odd:w 
\if_meaning:w 
\if_mode_horizontal:
\if_mode_inner: 
\if_mode_math:
\if_mode_vertical:
\if_predicate:w 
\if_true: 
\if_vbox:N
```

There is also this one:

```
\IfValueTF
```

to check for argument presence.

I am wondering though how to just compare arbitrary value types to each other. The reason for this is because the input values might be anything, and it should be testable against a specific value of interest.

For example, I would like to be able to do this:

```
\ifeq \something 10 % integer
\ifeq \something true % boolean
\ifeq \something 10.12 % float
\ifeq \something foo=bar % prop list
\ifeq \something [1,2,3] % seq
```

where `\something` is the same arbitrary variable, so it would end up essentially being:

```
\ifeq 5 10
\ifeq 5 true
\ifeq 5 10.12
\ifeq 5 foo=bar
\ifeq 5 [1,2,3]
% or
\ifeq foo 10
\ifeq foo true
\ifeq foo 10.12
\ifeq foo foo=bar
\ifeq foo [1,2,3]
% or
\ifeq a=b 10
\ifeq a=b true
\ifeq a=b 10.12
\ifeq a=b foo=bar
\ifeq a=b [1,2,3]
% etc.
```

Wondering how to go about doing this sort of typechecking. The MWE I have so far is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\gettype}{m}{
  ... return int % if int
  ... return clist % if clist
  ... return proplist % if prop list
  ... return seq % if seq
  ... return bool % if boolean
  ...
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ifeq}{mmmO{}}{
  % int case
  \if \gettype{#1} == int {
    \if \gettype{#2} != int {
      \#4 % false branch
    }
    \else {
      % comparison for each type perhaps, not sure
      \if #1 == #2 {
        \#3
      }
    }
  }

  % i'd handle all these cases somehow once i understand
  % boolean case
  % float case
  % prop list case
  % seq case
  % clist case
  % tl case
}

\begin{document}

\ifeq{5}{10}
\ifeq{5}{true}
\ifeq{5}{10.12}
\ifeq{5}{foo=bar}
\ifeq{5}{[1,2,3]}
% or
\ifeq{foo}{10}
\ifeq{foo}{true}
\ifeq{foo}{10.12}
\ifeq{foo}{foo=bar}
\ifeq{foo}{[1,2,3]}
% or
\ifeq{a=b}{10}
\ifeq{a=b}{true}
\ifeq{a=b}{10.12}
\ifeq{a=b}{foo=bar}
\ifeq{a=b}{[1,2,3]}
% etc.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I fear you're want to use `type-casting` in LaTeX, which is not really possible.

Comment: Not really good code but you could test the given argument with `\regex_match:nnTF` to check for the type of input and only if the pattern matches execute the correct comparison, else return false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is just a proposal. **I don't think this should ever be used**, but it shows how one could implement some checks on which type of input there is and defining variables of certain type.

It implements this for the types `tl`, `str`, `int`, and `fp`. To further extent it, one would have to define a regular expression which should be matched for the new data type and a comparing function which has to be added to the `str_case:nn`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
% regexes for comparison
\regex_const:Nn \c_lance_pollard_tl_regex { \A.*\Z }% could be anything
\regex_const:Nn \c_lance_pollard_str_regex { \A\c[OS].*\Z }% could be anything
\regex_const:Nn \c_lance_pollard_int_regex { \A[+\-]?\d+\Z }
\regex_const:Nn \c_lance_pollard_fp_regex { \A[+\-]?\d+\.?\d*\Z }

\NewDocumentCommand\newsomething{ m }
  {
    % #1 : type
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { str }
      { \newsomethingVerbatim { #1 } }
      { \newsomethingNormal { #1 } }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\newsomethingNormal { m m +m }
  {
    % #1 : type
    % #2 : name
    % #3 : value
    \lance_pollard_new_something:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\newsomethingVerbatim { m m +v }
  {
    % #1 : type
    % #2 : name
    % #3 : value
    \lance_pollard_new_something:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \lance_pollard_new_something:nnn
  {
    % #1 : type
    % #2 : name
    % #3 : value
    \cs_if_exist:cTF { c_lance_pollard_#1_regex }
      {
        \exp_args:Nc \regex_match:NnTF { c_lance_pollard_#1_regex } { #3 }
          {
            \tl_set:cn { l_lance_pollard_#2_type_tl } { #1 }
            \use:c { #1_new:c  } { l_lance_pollard_#2_val_#1 }
            \use:c { #1_set:cn } { l_lance_pollard_#2_val_#1 } { #3 }
          }
          {
            \msg_error:nnnnn { lance_pollard } { badly~formatted }
              { #3 } { #2 } { #1 }
          }
      }
      {
        \msg_error:nnn { lance_pollard } { type~not~setup } { #1 }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\ifsomethingeq { m }
  {
    % #1 : name
    \exp_args:Nx \str_if_eq:nnTF
      { \tl_use:c { l_lance_pollard_#1_type_tl } }
      { str }
      { \ifsomethingeqVerbatim { #1 } }
      { \ifsomethingeqNormal { #1 } }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\ifsomethingeqNormal { m +m +m +m }
  {
    % #1 : name which was defined with \newsomething
    % #2 : value to compare with
    % #3 : T
    % #4 : F
    \lance_pollard_if_something_eq:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\ifsomethingeqVerbatim { m +v +m +m }
  {
    % #1 : name which was defined with \newsomething
    % #2 : value to compare with
    % #3 : T
    % #4 : F
    \lance_pollard_if_something_eq:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \lance_pollard_if_something_eq:nnnn
  {
    % #1 : name which was defined with \newsomething
    % #2 : value to compare with
    % #3 : T
    % #4 : F
    \lance_pollard_if_something_eq:xnnTF
      { \tl_use:c { l_lance_pollard_#1_type_tl } } { #1 } { #2 }
      { #3 }
      { #4 }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \lance_pollard_if_something_eq:nnnTF
  {
    % #1 : type
    % #2 : name
    % #3 : value to compare with
    % #4 : T
    % #5 : F
    \lance_pollard_if_type:nnTF { #1 } { #3 }
      {
        \exp_args:Nnc 
          \lance_pollard_cmp_type:nNnTF { #1 }
            { l_lance_pollard_#2_val_#1 } { #3 }
            { #4 }
            { #5 }
      }
      { #5 }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \lance_pollard_if_something_eq:nnnTF { xnnTF }
\cs_new:Nn \lance_pollard_if_type:nnTF
  {
    % #1 : type
    % #2 : value to compare with
    % #3 : T
    % #4 : F
    \cs_if_exist:cTF { c_lance_pollard_#1_regex }
      {
        \exp_args:Nc \regex_match:NnTF { c_lance_pollard_#1_regex } { #2 }
          { #3 }
          { #4 }
      }
      {
        \msg_error:nnn { lance_pollard } { type~not~setup } { #1 }
        #4
      }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \lance_pollard_cmp_type:nNnTF
  {
    % #1 : type
    % #2 : name of macro storing value
    % #3 : value to compare with
    % #4 : T
    % #5 : F
    \str_case:nn { #1 }
      {
        { tl  } { \exp_args:NV \tl_if_eq:nnTF #2 { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } }
        { int } { \lance_pollard_cmp_int:nnTF { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } }
        { fp  } { \lance_pollard_cmp_fp:nnTF { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } }
        { str } { \str_if_eq:VnTF #2 { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \lance_pollard_cmp_int:nnTF
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF { #1 } = { #2 }
      { #3 }
      { #4 }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \lance_pollard_cmp_fp:nnTF
  {
    \fp_compare:nNnTF { #1 } = { #2 }
      { #3 }
      { #4 }
  }
\msg_new:nnn { lance_pollard } { type~not~setup }
  {
    The~used~type~'#1'~was~not~setup~for~use~with~\newsomething
    and~\ifsomethingeq.
  }
\msg_new:nnn { lance_pollard } { badly~formatted }
  {
    The~initial~value~'#1'~for~'#2'~doesn't~match~the~defined~format~of~the~
    type~'#3'.
  }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newsomething{fp}{myfp}{10.1}
\newsomething{int}{myint}{10}
\newsomething{tl}{mytl}{foobar}
\newsomething{str}{mystr}|$^_}{ern|

\begin{document}
\ifsomethingeq{myfp}{10.1}{equal}{not equal}

\ifsomethingeq{myint}{10}{equal}{not equal}

\ifsomethingeq{mytl}{foobar}{equal}{not equal}

\ifsomethingeq{mystr}|$^_}{ern|{equal}{not equal}

\ifsomethingeq{myfp}{foobar}{equal}{not equal}

\ifsomethingeq{myint}{foobar}{equal}{not equal}

\ifsomethingeq{mytl}{bazbang}{equal}{not equal}

\ifsomethingeq{mystr}{foobar}{equal}{not equal}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In a `str` only characters with category code 12 or 10 can appear.

Comment: It would be nice to have an API where you could do either `\mycmd{foo=1}` or `\mycmd{foo=[1,2,3]}`, then just check "if it's an integer, make it into a clist" to normalize. guess it's all just regexps.

Comment: @egreg, you're right, my bad...

Comment: @Skillmon Probably `\A(\cO.|\s)*\Z` to take care of space tokens.

Comment: @LancePollard sorry, except for correcting issues/errors, I don't have any interest in develop this any further. Feel free to use my code in any way you want, but I personally wouldn't use it. It just makes things more complicated, imho. Also `clist`s can store anything, not only integers.

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, indeed. Forgot the `.`

Answer (score 6):

There is no build in 'guess the data format' command in either `xparse` or `expl3`. In general, we expect input to be well-defined, whilst actually doing error checking on data types can be somewhat tricky.

Ultimately, all literal input in TeX is a token list. So we can always test if they are exactly the same: this is a code-level function

```
\tl_if_eq:nnTF { foo } {#1}
  { True code }
  { False code }
```

Much of the time, you will likely want to do a string test instead

```
\str_if_eq:nnTF { foo } {#1}
  { True code }
  { False code }
```

which differs in that it is catcode-agnostic.

Beyond this, you would need to define appropriate checking functions. The issue of course is what those might be. For example, `+-+-\numexpr 1 0\relax` is from a TeX point-of-view a perfectly reasonable number. Life gets even more 'interesting' with something like `[1,2,3]`, which is not a a sequence at all: it's a comma list. Several `expl3` data structures are constructed in a form that cannot be entered in a document, so they cannot be simply tested in the way asked.

Most likely, there are better approaches to the problem(s) at hand, but they depend upon the exact use case.

Comment: Interesting, I would be interested to see how bool and int are implemented as datatypes then, it seems like the literal string `true` would be what is checked, but I thought also maybe there is a special token list like xparse's `-NoValue-` for an empty argument. Maybe it's like `~~TRUE~~` or something. Maybe there is a null/undefined value as well like `NULL`. Haven't seen it in the docs yet.

Comment: @LancePollard It's all in `source3` (`texdoc source` to see it).  At the code level, bools are currently implemented as the chars `0` and `1`: the previous version had `00` and `01`, and before that there was the TeX `\iffalse` and `\iftrue` primitives. For `int`, we've always used the TeX `\count` registers. However, the point of `expl3` is that you don't rely on the implementation: we aim to document the way things are supposed to be used.

Comment: well, you still have the `\numexpr` problem beacuse TeX will fetch the 1 and leave 0\relax if I do `\count200=+-+-\numexpr 1 0\relax` ... `:)`

Comment: perhaps state that `-(1)` is not legal in `\numexpr`. That's not widely known: `\count200=\numexpr-(1)\relax` --> `Missing number, treated as zero.`

Comment: @jfbu Not sure what you mean about `\numexpr`: spaces are ignored so `\numexpr 1 0` is the same as `\numexpr10`.

Comment: @jfbu More 'fun' is perhaps `\count0=\number+-+-\numexpr 0-(1) 5\relax` :)

Comment: @JosephWright no spaces are ignored only around operators. When etex parses `1 0` it gobbles the space after 1 looking for an operator, it finds the `0` hence it steps back and terminates. It leaves the `0` in the token stream. You can try it out with `\int_eval:n` `;-)`

Comment: and your `\number+-+-\numexpr 0-(1) 5\relax` illustrates that. The `\numexpr` removes the space, the `\number` then produces `-1` and we are with `\count0=-15\relax`. (better to make that near bottom of page I have a laptop so if not I have to scroll down to see the fun ;-) )

Comment: (regarding `\int_eval:n` trial, of course using `~` ...)